# best c audio library linux

Tags: c, linux, audio

I was wondering if anyone had an opinion on what they think is the best linux audio library for c. I'm just learning and was experimenting with audio output on libao.

edit: right now all I'm trying to do is put out frequency tones.

Comment: Main question is what are you want to do with the audio library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try FMod. [You can get it here.](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-downloads.html)
It has a high level api, supports lots of programming languages and operating systems.
Lots of audio formats can be played, and encoded, there is also support for 3d-sound and much more. It is free for non-commercial use and has various licensing models for commercial uses.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open source audio api called [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx) available.  I haven't used it but I have heard good things about it.

Comment: I strongly advise against OpenAL. I wrote the audio backend for my program only to discover that OpenAL's default Linux implementation in Linux (SI) is essentially broken, and the other one (Soft) still suffers from performance and compatibility issues.