# C++ Sound Processing

Tags: c++, signal-processing, audio

I'm looking for a library that could be used to manipulate audio files. Essentially what I would like to do is:

1. Load an MP3/WAV file
2. Get a 15 second clip of the file
3. Overlay another MP3/WAV file ontop of it
4. Render as a new MP3/WAV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any common MP3 codec API to decode the stream, work with it, and save it again.  For instance you could use [libLAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) for this part.

As for mixing, you could either do it yourself (e.g., naively, add two samples and divide by two -- which might not sound too good), or find a proper library for it.

You might also be interested in a related Stack Overflow question at [best c audio library linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042752/best-c-audio-library-linux)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't support MP3 for patent reasons, but [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) is a very nice open-source (LGPL) library for loading and saving audio in a variety of other audio formats, including WAV.

As for the overlay part, that's easy once you've got the samples loaded into memory... you just sum each sample in file A with its corresponding sample in file B (and possibly scale the resulting sample value down a bit by multiplying by a constant, if you're worried about clipping).

Answer (score 1):

The library [libsox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/libsox.html) from sox (and not http://libsox.sourceforge.net/ which is something completely different) seems to have a simple API which can be used. The documentation gives the following example for stereo to mono mixing:

> Representing samples as integers can
>   cause problems when processing the
>   audio. For example, if an effect to
>   mix down left and right channels into
>   one monophonic channel were to use the
>   line

```
    *obuf++ = (*ibuf++ + *ibuf++)/2;
```

> distortion might occur since the
>   intermediate addition can overflow 32
>   bits. The line

```
    *obuf++ = *ibuf++/2 + *ibuf++/2;
```

> would get round the overflow problem
>   (at the expense of the least
>   significant bit).

Answer (score 0):

You might try giving this a look over
http://terminatorx.org/
I was looking at it to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

A very good C++ audio/synth library is [STK](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/classes.html). It does loads of stuff and is under BSD/MIT type license ie you can use it to develop commercial products. Wav is supported but not MP3. For MP3 you could use [irrklang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/), for example, which is free for non-commercial use (also MAD by underbit, is used by loads of people).