# c program to play audio file

Tags: c, audio

Can you give an example code to play an audio file in the C language, along with what header files are needed? I am new to this concept.... I am interested to learn this.

Comment: The 'c' language does not do sound. It's the libraries and operating system you program for that does the sound. You haven't specified what OS, what type of audio, the audio source and so on.

Comment: There's no standard way to do it. It depends on your platform, your libs, etc.

Comment: Stack overflow gives you a big box to write your question, and presumably you have access to a full-size keyboard. There's no reason to use "txt-speak" like "u" and "dis" in your questions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PortAudio library. PortAudio is a free, cross platform, open-source, audio I/O library.  It lets you write simple audio programs in 'C' that will compile and run on many platforms including Windows, Macintosh (8,9,X), Unix (OSS), SGI, and BeOS. PortAudio is intended to promote the exchange of audio synthesis software between developers on different platforms.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it in C alone, you're going to have to involve something platform-specific.

One way of doing that in a way that still remains very portable, is to use existing multimedia libraries, such as [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Answer (score 4):

See [best c audio library linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042752/best-c-audio-library-linux)

On *nix: Simply print a raw audio file to /dev/audio