# Audio support for programming languages

Tags: audio, programming-languages

I want to start on a hobby project that focuses on displaying audio files in a folder in a certain fashion and has the ability to play such an audio file and shows basic control options for playing. However, i'm struggling to find a fit programming language for this.

The **displaying part** shouldn't be too hard and can probably be done in most of the programming languages.   The **audio part** is what concerns me the most since it's not the main focus of the project and should only do limited things (so it shouldn't be too hard) and i do not know anything about sound support in the programming languages i currently know. (Java, C and C++)

Specifically i would like to be able to do these things:

1. *Play* a sound file
2. *Stop/pause* a playing song
3. Adjust *volume*
4. Show a bar that displays the *current position* in the song

Most files will be **.mp3** files but being able to process other formats is certainly a plus. Since this is just a small project it's ok if it runs just on **Windows**. Scalabilty would be nice but not required.

It would be nice to have a small overview of audio support/audio libraries of programming languages (i'm always up for something new) that can accomplish these simple things, in a not too complicated way, aswell as personal experiences.

In this way i hope to create a better understanding of which programming language fits my project best. (i would very much like to not have to change language mid-way the project)

--

**Edit**:
This is only for a later stage of the project if the first part was successfull: i will want to change the file names of the audio files that are displayed. (to make them follow a specific format)

Comment: How about a web app that runs in a browser? You could learn HTML5 + Javascript, which are always nice skills to have nowadays.. There exists an <audio> html5 tag which can be controlled by Javascript : http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-the-html5-audio-property

Comment: Sounds nice actually, but from a performance POV i'm not sure it's feasible. The size of the audio folder i'll want to display (and frequently sync!) is 100Gb and a typical 'song' will be around 100-200Mb. What i forgot to mention is that in a later stage i'd like to do some actual processing on the file names of the songs (making the file names follow a uniform format) which i think won't be possible. I'll edit that in :)

Comment: 100-200Mb, what kind of 'song' is that? + i don't see why you couldn't rename your files later, they would be placed on your server and you can do as you please, people rename web files all the time ! it's no problem as long as you update your HTML pages accordingly.

Comment: + if that's a project you're willing to share with people, a web server is exactly what you need = sync in one place, instantly available to anyone.

Comment: There are actually a LOT of C/C++ libraries for audio processing and playback. Most of what you are asking for is also just a few processing on your side. For example, what percentage of the audio has passed. Have you tried searching on the internet for such a library?

Comment: @Darma the songs are called Livesets (mostly digital music), they're recordings of everything an artist played on a festival or are a series of songs mixed together by an artist and then made available on the internet, typically anywhere between half an hour up to even 4 hours. There actually is a site which links (not hosts!) to all sorts of different livesets. Hosting all these would take an incredible amount of resources, which i do not possess or, currently, am willing to pay for.

Comment: @Shahbaz Ok so C/C++ have libraries, that's what i was looking for. I was hoping for a few names of many used libraries but this certainly provides me a starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't written audio processing programs much, but I know a lot of them exist for C and C++. For Java perhaps, too, but I don't know Java. I had used audio with [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) in a game, but that doesn't have that many features and I don't recommend it.

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1042752/912144) asking for a library in C, and there are a couple of similar questions that SO brings up on the side. You may want to take a look at those.

You would also need to look for a library that loads different file types. SDL at least, only opens `.wav` files, which I believe most of the playback libraries would support. For MP3, you will most likely need an additional library. I know [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) uses [LAME Mp3](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) so I'm guessing that should be good.

Some of the functionalities you want is also doable by yourself. For example, knowing the length of the music and the amount you have already read, you will know how far in the audio you are. Adjusting the volume is also a multiplication (in the simplest case) that you can do on the audio data if the library doesn't provide it.

A very good choice seems to be [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) which is [used by Audacity](http://www.portaudio.com/apps.html), and also recommended in the accepted answer of the question I mentioned above.

Comment: Many thanks. Looks like i'll be going C++ and start looking up the libraries you mentioned.

Comment: Update: wwise is famous now!

Answer (score 0):

I've done audio apps in both Java and C++. Java development goes way faster because it's a more powerful language and has garbage collection, but JavaSound is a pretty awful solution for audio. Of course, there are wrappers for FFMPEG and other stuff, so you can get a lot of things working. Here's an example of a Java audio app: http://www.indabamusic.com/help/mantis

OTOH, C++ gives you lots of control, low latency and wealth of libraries. (another answer mentioned Portaudio, which is, indeed, great.) But you will definitely find it also has a much longer development cycle.

You can certainly do everything you want to do with either language.